# How to secure all controller if user not authed?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.2 and I am interested how to secure all controller if user is not authorized.

In this case user should be redirect to login page.
I try to make this using routing.

I set this code above all routes:

```
Route::auth();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use middleware. It will help to filter and secure all routes

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware

Comment: Okay, I can add `'middleware' => 'auth'` for each controller, but how to add this for all controllers one time?

Comment: @Dev create route group https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-middleware

Answer (score 1):

You have to just wrap up all needed routes by middleware group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('path1');
    Route::get('path2');
    Route::get('path3');
    etc....
});
```

Also you need to create middleware class and register it in kernel